# make vnc server listen on guest's ip address

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization, qemu

My host system has the IP `192.168.0.250`. Now I want to create a kvm guest using a tap device (so the network card of the guest just acts like a "real" one). The guest has a static ip `192.168.0.249` which it setups on his own (no dhcp). To connect to the guest using VNC I can to use the host's IP. So far everything works fine.

Now I wonder how I can make the VNC server to listen on the guest's IP address, so I can use the guest's IP address to connect using my vnc client. Of course I cannot use `-vnc 192.168.0.249:1` as this IP is not active on the host and so fails with `Cannot assign requested address`. Can this be done with `tap` networking at all? If not, how to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to VNC into the guest machine, simply start VNC inside the guest machine. Once you can get to the guest from outside the host, treat the guest as if it's just another separate host on the network.

Comment: I do not want to run the VNC Server inside the guest. This way I would not be able to access the BIOS, choose which drive to boot, etc. There must be a way to use the vnc server provided by them qemu/ kvm process using the guest's ip.

Comment: There isn't. If you want VNC access to the guest, you have to run the VNC server in the guest. What it seems like you want is a VNC session in the host to the guest's graphical console - but it will be on the host's IP, not the guest's.

Answer (score 0):

The guest's IP is set up in the guest OS, qemu runs on the host.  There is no way to have the host and the guest share an IP